# Parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch:

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, mod-perl

I have a problem reading XML file. If you please look at xml below you see element `<fl> ?fl>` instead of `<fl></fl>`. I receive error opening and ending tag mismatch.

How to:

1. There are an errors in XML file such as `<fl> ?fl>` instead of `<fl></fl>`. How to ignore such error or fix them while reading xml and than use it for parsing?
2. I only want to read content from `$_->{desc}->[0]->{en}->[0]` and NOT from `<de>`, `<es>`, `<fl>`.

Now I'm reading XML file like:

```
package test::test6382_sunseekingeurope;
use strict;
use warnings;
use test;
use base qw/test/;
use URI::URL;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use constant TASK_ID => 6382;
use constant CR_TYPE => '6382';
use constant IMAGE_PATH => "/home/testco/public_html/files/";#"images/";

sub new
{
my $class = shift;
my $self = $class->SUPER::new(CR_TYPE, TASK_ID);
bless $self, $class;

my $url = 'http://www.onbip.com/xml/sunseeking9.xml';

my $xml = $self->geturl('url'=>$url);
$self->extract($xml);
}

sub extract{
my $self = shift;
my $xmlfile = shift;
my $xml = new XML::Simple(ForceArray=>1,'KeyAttr' =>'image');
my $data = $xml->XMLin($xmlfile);

foreach(@{$data->{property}}){
    my $property = &makeScalar($_->ID->[0]);
    my $description = &makeScalar($_->{desc}->[0]->{en}->[0]);
```

XML:

```
<property>
<id>226887</id>
<desc>
 <en>
  Nice house in the center of Alhaurin de la Torre with walking distance to all amenities.
 </en>
 <es>
  Bonita casa mata en Alhaurin de la Torre con vistas a la montana, se puede acceder caminando al centro, colegios, etc.
 </es>
  <de>
    guter zustand, bezaubernde immobilie,
  </de>
  <fl>
    bon n acces par la route, partiellement meubl?a proximit?'?les, partiellement r?v
  ?fl>
</desc>
</property>
```

Comment: Please, next time use the proper formating.

Comment: The code you show does not read XML, it only walks through a Perl data structure. I guess you are using a module for parsing XML but what you have is clearly not XML...

Answer (score 1):

There is no general way to fix an error in an XML file.  All you can do is reject the file as invalid XML.  [The error handling documentation for XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-1.08/Simple.pm#ERROR_HANDLING) explains:

> The XML standard is very clear on the issue of non-compliant
>   documents. An error in parsing any single element (for example a
>   missing end tag) must cause the whole document to be rejected.

The basic problem is this: once you allow that a file contains errors, it could contain literally anything.  There is no way of parsing that.  There is really no way of knowing what should be "corrected".

If, for whatever reason, your input has a very specific, predictable error, you could detect that with a regex before passing it to `XML::Simple`.  As long as you know that a few specific closing tags will have `?` or `?/` instead of `</`, you could do something like this:

```
my $xmlfile = shift;

my $xml = new XML::Simple(ForceArray=>1,'KeyAttr' =>'image');

#Try it to parse the file as is first.
my $data = eval { $xml->XMLin($xmlfile) };

#On error, try fixing.
if ($@)
{
    $xmlfile =~ s/\?\/?(desc|en|es|de|fl)>/<\/$1>/g;
    $data = eval { $xml->XMLin($xmlfile) };
    if ($@) 
    { 
        die "Failed to process the file even after attempting corrections: $@"; 
    }
}
```

Using a regex in this way has its dangers--you are relying on the input XML being in a particular format.  However, the potential damage is at least minimized by trying to process the file normally first.  That way you are only doing something risky in a case where the file was going to fail anyway.

*Update: added error handling to second `XMLIn()` call.*

*Update 2: I updated the regex to match only the exact cases that the questioner needed (in a case like this, it is best to be as specific as possible to avoid false positive matches).*

Comment: How to replace ?/fl> with </fl> in  $xmlfile =~ s/\?(\w+>)/<\/$1/g;
and use both regex?

Comment: This single regex will fix either `?/fl>` or `?fl>`: `$xmlfile =~ s/\?\/?(\w+>)/<\/$1/g;`  However, beware: this problem will get very messy if there are more than a couple of types of simple, predictable errors!  You need to make sure that you know exactly what your input format could be, and that you have handled all possible cases.  If you can't do that, then you probably should not be using a regex for this.

Comment: I have errors only in XML for this elements: <desc>-><en> <es> <de> <fl> </desc>

Comment: @user1059749, are the errors all in the closing tags, or could they be in the opening ones too?  If they could be in the opening or closing tags, it will be a real problem to tell them apart. e.g. you could not tell if `?es>` meant `<es>` or `</es>`.

Comment: Only closing tag. It should be: if ('?es>' OR '?/es>') than </es> .

Comment: @user1059749, ok, it should be all right then.  I have updated the answer with a more specific regex that will be safer.

Comment: Problem is now only in <desc><en>lounge/dining</en></desc>. How to replace this kind of string with '/',  because problem is in '/' between lounge and dinning string and '/' should be replaced with string ' and '. And also there could be different kind of string instead of 'lounge'/'dinning' ?

Comment: @user1059749, is this causing the XML parser to fail?

Comment: I think so, because script has been stopped in some id which have <desc><en>lounge/dining</en></desc>. And I manually remove this from xml and script go to the next id.

Comment: And one more question: I'd like to replace &#038; with and, is it correct? $xmlfile =~ s/&#038;/and/g;

Comment: @user1059749, that regex is correct.  However, unless this is causing the `XMLIn()` function to fail, you should make the changes after the XML is parsed.  That is the safest.